# what object-based shells are there?

Tags: shell, oop, powershell, pipe

I am planning to write an object-oriented shell (based on Python). I have many ideas already. But before I am going to implement it, I want to inspire me by some existing shell.

What I basically mean by object-oriented:

- Parameters are not just an array of strings but an array of objects.
- The return value is also an object.
- There is not just stdin, stdout and stderr but any possible number of named streams which can be of certain types (not just a stream of bytes).

I have read that the Windows PowerShell is somewhat like that (based on .Net). Though I am searching for some existing Linux/MacOSX shells.

Of course there is also IPython but it is not really intended as a Unix shell, i.e. piping stuff around is quite complicated.

Comment: no such thing. powershell is the only truely object-based shell afaik. heaven forbid: microsoft innovating!

Comment: Did this ever go any further? I have also been thinking about writing a proper object-oriented shell as I believe it greatly simplifies management and shell scripting.

Comment: I get fed up with my for loops falling on their ass because of spaces in filenames. I know there's ways round it but it's a pain. It's time we caught up with powerhell!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you may want to take a look at [Pash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pash_(software)).

It is an open source implementation of the PowerShell for other platforms. For educational purposes and inspiration it might be useful. Unfortunately, as far as I can see, this promising project is not being developed.

Comment: There are plans to revive it within [MOSA](http://mosa-project.org/projects/mosa); they are intending for Pash to be the default shell. But that may still take a while.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft's PowerShell (Core), installed by default on modern versions of Windows, can be installed on Linux too. It's a really good tool, a bit long to warm-up, but once it's done it's really useful.

The features I really love in it is the filtering :

```
 ls | Where-Object { $_.size -eq 0 }
```

who can be rewritten in the compact form

```
 ls | ? { $_.size -Eq 0 }
```

and the transformation (followed by it's compact form ):

```
 ls | Foreach-Object { $_.name -replace "\folderName","daba" }
 ls | % { $_.name -replace "\folderName","daba" }
```

you can also easily create pipe filter within the shell language, which is a pretty neat feature.

```
Function concat()
{
    Begin { $rez = ""; }
    Process { $rez = $rez + $_ }
    End { $rez }
}


ls | % { $_.name } | concat
```

The last expression list all files, extract the filename and concatenate them in a single string (it might be some commandlet to do that, but I don't remember the name).

Another important part of the PowerShell, is the introspection, you can query your object property/methods from the command line :

```
ls | Get-Member
```

Really useful to play with new objects, it's a bit more descriptive than `dir()`from python
[1]: http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx

Comment: I don't have Windows. I am searching for some non-Windows shell.

Comment: @Albert: `ksh` at least allowed serialized objects, but I have no clue how it works exactly. It's also cited as an inspiration for the PowerShell language.

Comment: whilst a nice wishlist, this isn't an answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

According to the [shell comparison list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_command_shells), the only existing shells which can do that are MS PowerShell and IPython (if that counts as a command shell) with the [IPipe extension](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/UsingIPipe) for piping.

<s>If you only count real cross platform solutions, MS PowerShell cannot be used</s>.
This is outdated, PowerShell is cross-platform now.

There is also the [Pash](http://pash.sourceforge.net/) port of it (thanks Roman to notice it), though it is incomplete and thus not really useable.

Comment: This answer is outdated. As of 2016, PowerShell is available for Linux and macOS, in addition to Windows. https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/