# object-oriented shell for linux?

Tags: linux, oop, shell, powershell

Is there anything similar to Microsoft Powershell (an object-oriented shell built on the .NET framework) for Linux (possibly built on Java, GObject, or its own object type/nothing)?

edit: especially if similar to bash or powershell or cmd etc. syntax (=''standard'' shell syntax)

Comment: I don't think it would be useful.

Comment: @DaVinci: I've done "touch foo.ext; cvs add foo.ext; $EDITOR foo.ext" often enough to think a map operation or jQueryesque semantics could be interesting. Yes, "for op in touch "cvs add" $EDITOR; do $op foo.ext;done" might work, but is more typing than doing it manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [what object-based shells are there?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281442/what-object-based-shells-are-there) and [Can anyone recommend a good modern alternative to bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85736/can-anyone-recommend-a-good-modern-alternative-to-bash)

Comment: @Ulrich: `function whatever { touch "$1" ; cvs add "$1" ; $EDITOR "$1" ; }` is not sufficient for you? If you really wanted to do it the way you describe you can of course employ eval.

Comment: see also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/object-oriented-shell-for-nix

Comment: This is the battle between BASH'ers vs. PowerShell'ers.

Answer (score 13):

Python.  No joking.

Scripting languages are scripting languages, and Python is a particularly nice one that many people find very approachable.

Comment: The usual scripting languages aren't very good at what shells are designed for: invoking programs, referencing files, plugging things together with pipes.

Comment: Partly true, especially at the prompt. But when a bash script grows a little, before looking in the manual how to handle exceptions, or trying to remember the One True Obscure Secure Way to delete stuff in /tmp/, I scrap and rewrite in python

Comment: @ak2 os.system() and the rest of the os package makes that easy

Comment: Of course it's possible to do all the things that shells are good at from Python and others, but it just isn't anywhere near as convenient, particularly for interactive use. The scripting language equivalents of shell commands are usually much more verbose (`os.listdir('.')` anyone?), and tab completion isn't the same if it's enabled at all. But I agree with Marko, for bigger scripts, 'shell' is not a pleasant programming language.

Answer (score 8):

Even though this question is pretty old, I think its worth mentioning that in August 2016 Microsoft made Powershell open-source and cross platform. Instructions for installation are on github.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell

Comment: Good thing nobody noticed the question was off-topic until you posted this answer :-)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the update!

Comment: This is hilariously blasphemous, and I love it.

Comment: I tried this once, has anyone gotten this working on the Linux sdie?

Answer (score 5):

#### Perl, Python, and Ruby

---

Ok, I'm sure you already know that, but someone had to say it.

Perl is the oldest and most popular.

If you like objects, you will probably love Ruby. It has an elaborate object system inspired by Smalltalk.

Python has this cool block-structure-by-indent syntax.

Unix is a gold mine of advanced scripting tools...

Comment: ... yet none of them are any good at replacing an interactive Unix shell.

Comment: Perl is pretty ancient. And I highly doubt it is more popular than Python as of 2018

Answer (score 1):

[Hotwire](http://code.google.com/p/hotwire-shell/)

Comment: "Hypershell"? Last update two years ago? Sounds ideal.

Answer (score 1):

[NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) can do that, in fact it's one of the samples included in the download. Use it interactively, or (probably more usefully) write shell scripts in JavaScript.

For example:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node

var sys  = require('sys'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

// Run `ls`:
exec('ls -lh /usr', function(error, output, erroutput) {
    sys.print('output:    ' + output);
    sys.print('erroutput: ' + erroutput);
});
```

...but that's just the high-level interface that buffers all the output for you, etc. You can get a lot more down and dirty than that if you like.

NodeJS takes asynchronicity as the normal state of affairs, and so if you want a "traditional" shell script, you may find it's not a good match as it doesn't (as of this writing, as far as I know) offer a synchronous version of `exec`. So an ad hoc series of serial statements becomes an exercise in callbacks:

```
exec('first_command', function(error) {
    if (error != null) {
        exec('second_command', function(error) {
            if (error != null) {
                // ....
            }
        });
    }
});
```

...but of course, you can create a function that handles that for you and takes (say) an array of sequential statements to execute (and then install it as a module via Node's module sysstem). So for instance:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/node
var sys  = require('sys'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec;

execSeries([
    'ls -ld /usr',
    'foobar',
    'ls -ld /etc'
], {echo: true}, function(results) {
    sys.print("Done\n");
});

// ===> This would be in a module, not in the script itself <===
function execSeries(series, options, callback) {
    var index = 0,
        results = [];

    // Make 'options' optional
    if (!callback && typeof options === "function") {
        callback = options;
        options = undefined;
    }

    // Default options
    options = options || {};

    // Go
    callNext();

    function callNext() {
        if (index >= series.length) {
            // Done
            callback(results);
        }
        else {
            // Call the next one
            exec(series[index++], function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                // Record result
                results.push({error: error, stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr});

                // Echo?
                if (options.echo) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        sys.print(stdout);
                    }
                    else {
                        sys.print("Error: " + error + "\n");
                    }
                }

                // Stop on error?
                if (options.breakOnError && error != null) {
                    // Yes, and there was an error; stop
                    callback(results);
                }
                else {
                    // No, continue
                    callNext();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink why it is you think you need an object-oriented shell. That said, if you're set trying weird shells you can't go wrong with [zoid](http://search.cpan.org/~pardus/Zoidberg-0.96/man1/zoid.pod). Unlike many of the other suggestions I see here it really is a shell. On the other hand, if you don't know or don't like Perl you probably won't be happy.

Comment: why not? it's better than having to parse all output as a string

Comment: All output is not a string, all output is a *stream of bytes*, which is the ground truth of computing. You can trivially make higher order objects on top of that and you can make tools which exchange these objects all without requiring support from the shell. Shell support doesn't make it significantly easier and this is apparent from the lack of popular shells which work at an object level. You just don't need it. If you want to try it out there are several options (I linked one) but you'll find them of *limited utility* vs. more traditional shells.

Answer (score 0):

[jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is not quite an object-oriented shell, but it provides some of the benefits which object-oriented shells may have; I use it a lot, together with shell scripts, for such tasks.